# Remove-QADObject in Powershell needs interaction. Needs a way out

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script to delete very old AD accounts.

It works, but when I run it from PowershellGUI, it prompts for you to click yes/no. I looked through [PowerGUI's Remove-QADObject documentation](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Remove-QADObject), but there is no mention of a silent mode. Does anyone know a work-around?

```
# Get the date that is about 6 months ago from today.
$dateObj = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

$oldADUsers = Get-QADUser -SearchRoot "OU=expired_test,OU=Students,DC=..." -AccountExpiresBefore $dateObj

foreach ($user in $oldADUsers)
{
    Remove-QADObject $user
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false`. `-Confirm:$false` tells the cmdlet to not prompt for confirmation. `-Force` may not be required, but it sometimes is. I don't have QAD-module to test if it's required here, but it won't do any harm to include it.

```
# Get the date that is about 6 months ago from today.
$dateObj = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

$oldADUsers = Get-QADUser -SearchRoot "OU=expired_test,OU=Students,DC=..." -AccountExpiresBefore $dateObj

foreach ($user in $oldADUsers)
{
    Remove-QADObject $user -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it on Monday morning! Really appreciated.